# How can I model continuous variable to a given precision without creating large numbers of redundant nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a challenge which must be common but I can't find how to do it! I know it has been solved in time trees but how is it done?

I want to model a product dimension in mm, the possible range is from zero to 3000mm and the resolution is down to 0.001mm. The vast majority of values will be between 50 and 150 mm but any value in this range is possible. I could create a hub node and then child, next, last nodes covering the entire range in decades (so simpler than time trees!) but then I would have 3,000,000 nodes labelled "Dimension" before I stored a single piece of data...

How can I set up a system that recognises when I have generated a new node for, say 68.55 mm, and fits it into the correct place in the tree generating any missing nodes and relationships required to populate the tree and deleting surplus relationships?

I imagine there is standard piece of code for this?